# how to append a new hyperlink with a new id each time in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's my second day on this project :\

I'm trying to create is : creating a new `<a>` element with a new `href` and `id` attributes in  `for` loop so that I can get each output of the API as a link.

This is my JS Code

```
var one;
var two;
var hoba;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inp").keyup(function() {
    hoba = $(this).val();
  });

  $("#but").on("click", function() {
    var app = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&list=search&titles=Main+Page&rvprop=content&origin=*&srsearch=" + hoba;

    $.getJSON(app, function(data) {
      for (i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
        console.log(app);
        one = $("<a></a>").text(data.query.search[i].title);

        //var _href = $("a").attr("href");
        $("a").attr("href", 'https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + data.query.search[i].title);
        $("a").attr("id", data.query.search[i].title);

        two = document.createElement("p");
        two.innerHTML = data.query.search[i].snippet;
        $("body").append(one, two);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Add the `attr` and `id` to `one`. So, `$("a").attr("href",..` should be `one.attr("href",..` and so on for the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same object to set attributes

```
one = $("<a></a>");
one.text(data.query.search[i].title);
one.attr("href", 'https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + data.query.search[i].title);
one.attr("id", data.query.search[i].title);
```

Use [`jQuery( html, attributes )`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) to create HTML element.

```
var anchor = $("<a></a>", {
    "text": data.query.search[i].title,
    "href": 'https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + data.query.search[i].title,
    "id": data.query.search[i].title
});

$("body").append(anchor);
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#inp").keyup(function() {
    hoba = $(this).val();
  });

  $("#but").on("click", function() {

    var app = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&list=search&titles=Main+Page&rvprop=content&origin=*&srsearch=" + hoba;

    $.getJSON(app, function(data) {
      for (i = 0; i < data.query.search.length; i++) {
        var anchor = $("<a></a>", {
          "text": data.query.search[i].title,
          "href": 'https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + data.query.search[i].title,
          "id": data.query.search[i].title
        });

        var p = $("<p></p>", {
          "html": data.query.search[i].snippet
        });

        $("body").append(anchor);
        $("body").append(p);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should to do minor changes in your code as below.

Change code are in between 
// Changes Code Start and  // Changes Code End

```
var one;
var two;
var hoba;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#inp").keyup(function(){
             hoba = $(this).val();
        });
  $("#but").on("click",function(){

    var app = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=revisions&list=search&titles=Main+Page&rvprop=content&origin=*&srsearch="+hoba;

// Changes Code Start

    $.getJSON(app,function(data){
      for(i=0; i<data.query.search.length; i++){
        console.log(app);
        var dataAppend;

    var title = data.query.search[i].title;
    var href = 'https://www.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + data.query.search[i].title;
    var id = data.query.search[i].title;

        dataAppend = "<a href='"+href+"' id='"+id+"'>"+title+"</a>";
        dataAppend += "<p>"+data.query.search[i].snippet+"</p>";

        // \"
        $("body").append(dataAppend);
      }

    });

// Changes Code End

  });
});
```